# Laravel join tables to get attribute from each one

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have these 3 Tables:

```
warehouses: id | warehouse_name
```

---

```
good_quantities: id | good_id | warehouse_id | quantity
```

---

```
goods: id | good_name
```

I'm trying to get all records in *good quantities*, And want to display it in a **View** like this:

```
good_name | warehouse_name | quantity |
```

What is the right query to get this result with Eloquent?

**Good Model**

```
class Good extends Model
{

/**
 * Get the Good Quantity for this Good.
 */
public function good_quantities()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Good_Quantity','good_id');
}

}
```

**Warehouse Model**

```
class Warehouse extends Model
{
/**
 * Get the Goods Quantity for this Warehouse.
 */
public function good_quantities()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Good_Quantity','warehouse_id');
}

}
```

**Good_Quantity Model**

```
class Good_Quantity extends Model
{

/**
 * Get the Good's Info.
 */
public function good()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Good','good_id');
}

/**
 * Get the Good Quantity's Warehouse.
 */
public function warehouse()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Warehouse','warehouse_id');
}

}
```

---

Comment: First of all, you can use belongsToMany for warehouse and goods

Comment: Learn Many-to-Many Relationship: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//you can get by using join
//in good model
       function function_name(){
$data=App\Good::join('good_quantities','good_quantities.good_id','=','good.good_id')
 ->join('warehouses','warehouses.warehouse_id','=','good_quantities.warehouse_id')
->select('good_name','warehouse_name','quantity')->get();
        }
```